# Libvirt does not see updated LVM volume

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, libvirt

All VMs run off an LVM pool.

I resized one of the LVM volumes to increase VMs drive copacity.
Resized it with `lvextend` as usual.
Everything is successful and `lvs` shows the new size.

Libvirt does not see the new size though. I try refreshing - no luck.
It still shows old capacity.

Running `virsh vol-info` on the volume shows the old size in capacity entry and the new size in allocation entry. Why is this so? It never used to be like this. Increasing an LVM volume would propagate and be visible after a refresh.

Now, the only way to get this new size to the VM is to reboot, which is out of the question. How can I make the new size visible?

**EDIT**

OS: Arch
Libvirt: 1.3.0
Qemu: 2.4.1

Restarting libvirt service does not help either. The volume still shows up with the old size in libvirt.

`lvs`

```
...      
  sswus00-vd0     vga  -wi-a----- 200.00g
...
```

`virsh vol-info --pool pool sswus00-vd0`

```
Name:           sswus00-vd0
Type:           block
Capacity:       100.00 GiB
Allocation:     200.00 GiB
```

So capacity is still at the old size and that is what VM gets.

**EDIT2**

This is really strange.

`lsblk` shows the old disk size for this lvm volume - 100G
 But `lvs` shows the new size - 200g

The back-end for the logical volume group is iSCSI.
So I thought maybe rescanning scsi bus would help.

Neither `echo "- - -" > echo "- - -" > /sys/devices/platform/host2/scsi_host/host2/scan`

or `iscsiadm -m node -R`

make any difference

Any ideas? How would I make kernel aware of the new size? And most important why it is doing this?

Comment: Hmm. Good question. It shouldn't matter much; the VM should already be able to use the extra space.

Comment: VM still sees the old size. Weird. I don't know when it started happening and after which update. I will update my questing with the outputs for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a qemu monitor command to the VM's qemu process to cause it to recognize the new size of the block device. For example:

```
virsh qemu-monitor-command vmname --hmp "block_resize drive/virtio-disk0 200G"
```

Note that `drive/virtio-disk0` refers to qemu's idea of the drive, which will vary depending on the driver in use (e.g. virtio or virtio-scsi) and which virtual drive it is in order (the 0 will change to a 1, 2, etc.). For a SCSI drive, you would have something like `drive-scsi0-0-0-0` where the numbers refer to the virtual controller, bus, target and LUN as defined in the libvirt XML.